# Problemas com a legenda de vídeos em HTML5

Tags: html, html5, html5-video

Fiz esse pequeno código baseado no que li na internet, mas as legendas não aparece, em nenhum navegador que eu testei.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<video poster="filmes/A-cabana-HD.jpg" class="embed-responsive" controls autoload>
  <source src="filmes/filme.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track label="Português" kind="subtitles" srclang="PT-BR" src="filmes/legenda.vtt" default/>
  <b>Por favor: entre com um navegador que tenha suporte a HTML5</b>
</video>
</div>
```

O que fazer para que as legendas funcione em HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe muito segredo no HTML5, mas a maior parte dos problemas ocorre porque:

1. O navegador/player do usuário simplesmente não oferece o suporte à legendas, ainda que ofereça suporte à vídeo.
2. O link para o src está errado, tente baixar manualmente pelo endereço indicado para ver o que aparece. Curiosamente o seu é `filmes/leghe da.vtt`.
3. O arquivo VTT de legendas existe, mas não é o formato esperado. Não é um STR mascarado com extensão VTT?
4. **Alguns navegadores não permitem rodar localmente, isto é, você precisa colocar no servidor de produção para funcionar.**

Comment: Estava mais para a 3° Opção. Só não entendi, não vi muita diferença na escrita do srt para vtt, eu coloquei *WEBVTT* no srt e renomeei para legenda.vtt mas não funcionou. Usei um conversor online e funcionou. Qual o segredo?

Comment: Existem algumas diferenças entres os dois formatos, leia a seção **Main differences from str**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebVTT. Mas a principal delas é a codificação do arquivo texto (o que não se enxerga apenas observando o conteúdo). WebVTT aceita somente UTF-8, é possível que seu SRT era ANSI.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!